# A moment when an incoming TX has been complitely settled and the coins may be sent out?

Tags: web3js, transactions, ether, ethers.js, raw-transaction

I have 2 wallets.

I want to send coins from one to the other (1), and from the 2nd one to an external wallet (2).

```
const wallet = get_wallet();
const balance = await provider.getBalance(wallet.address);
const gasPrice = await provider.getGasPrice();
const balanceMinusGas = balance.sub(gasPrice.mul(ETH_GAS_LIMIT));
let amountToSend = balanceMinusGas;



let tx = wallet.sendTransaction({
  to: MY_2ND_WALLET,
  gasLimit: ETH_GAS_LIMIT,
  gasPrice: gasPrice,
  value: amountToSend,
});

//
//sent only? but hasn't arrived, gotten mined, settled yet?
//
```

Once I've made a tx (1), how will one find out whether a TX **has been 100% settled**, or confirmed, mined, **and** the coins received such that they've **become available** for being sent out (2) further?

```
const receipt = await tx.wait();

// is it now 100% that the TX has been mined, confirmed, 
// **and** the ETH received
// may now be used by the 2nd wallet?

// TODO ...send the ETH out from MY_2ND_WALLET
```